# Javascript toggle working but shows unstyled menu

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails-5

On my ruby on rails 5 app I have a menu button that uses javascript to toggle the menu, the toggle function is showing and hiding the menu but the menu is not styled with css anymore

onclick the menu toggles like it should but all the elements are not styled, I dont know if its related to rails or I am missing something here

```js
//Toggle between adding and removing the "show_for_mobile" class to admin_side_bar when the user clicks on the icon
function toggleNav() {
  var x = document.getElementById("admin_side_bar");
  console.log(x.className)
  if (x.className === "admin_side_bar") {
    x.className += "show_for_mobile";
  } else {
    x.className = "admin_side_bar";
  }
}
```

```css
.admin_side_bar {
  width: 70%;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: #e2e6e8;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 60px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  display: none;
}

//show side bar on click
.show_for_mobile {
  display: block;
}

.admin_side_bar>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.admin_side_bar>ul>a {
  color: #3d3d3d;
  font-size: 19px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.admin_side_bar>ul>a:hover {
  color: #06bed3;
}

.admin_side_bar .fas {
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #afaeae;
}

.admin_side_bar .fas:hover {
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

.admin_side_bar>ul>a>li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!--Admin side bar-->
<div class="admin_side_bar" id="admin_side_bar">
  <ul>
    <a href="#">
      <li><i class="fas fa-home fa-fw fa-lg"></i>Home</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li><i class="fas fa-tshirt fa-fw fa-lg"></i>Items</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li><i class="fas fa-gift fa-fw fa-lg"></i>Orders</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li><i class="fas fa-chart-line fa-fw fa-lg"></i>Stats</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li><i class="fas fa-newspaper fa-fw fa-lg"></i>Blog</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add the `.show_for_mobile` class the original `display:none` from `.admin_side_bar` still takes precedence. If all you really want to do is show the nav then you can use `x.style.display = "block";` to overwrite `display:none` from the `admin_side_bar` class

`x.style.display="block"` works because it adds inline style which is the highest CSS specificity (it overwrites all other css rules).

From [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

> Inline styles added to an element (e.g., style="font-weight:bold") always overwrite any styles in external stylesheets, and thus can be thought of as having the highest specificity.

```js
document.getElementById("toggleButton").addEventListener("click", toggleNav);
//Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon
function toggleNav() {
  var x = document.getElementById("admin_side_bar");
  if (x.className === "admin_side_bar") {
    x.className += " show_for_mobile";
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.className = "admin_side_bar";
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.admin_side_bar {
  width: 70%;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: #e2e6e8;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 60px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  display: none;
}

//show side bar on click
.show_for_mobile {
  display: block !important;
}

.admin_side_bar>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.admin_side_bar>ul>a {
  color: #3d3d3d;
  font-size: 19px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.admin_side_bar>ul>a:hover {
  color: #06bed3;
}

.admin_side_bar .fas {
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #afaeae;
}

.admin_side_bar .fas:hover {
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

.admin_side_bar>ul>a>li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggleButton">Toggle Nav</button>
<!--Admin side bar-->
<div class="admin_side_bar" id="admin_side_bar">
  <ul>
    <a href="#">
      <li><i class="fas fa-home fa-fw fa-lg"></i>Home</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li><i class="fas fa-tshirt fa-fw fa-lg"></i>Items</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li><i class="fas fa-gift fa-fw fa-lg"></i>Orders</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li><i class="fas fa-chart-line fa-fw fa-lg"></i>Stats</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li><i class="fas fa-newspaper fa-fw fa-lg"></i>Blog</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```